# Bootstrap tooltip with long arrow with css or any other alternative

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I would to style my field tooltips to appear with long arrow so they don't cover the any subsequent field/icons after or below the control. Something like the image below.

How can I style bootstrap tooltips with a long arrow like in the image. Any CSS based cross browser compatible solution would be perfect.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code or something which you would have tried first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to post more code/details before expecting people here to just help do it for you.

Here's a simple demo:

```js
$('.btn').tooltip({
  boundary: 'window'
})
```

```css
button.btn {
  margin: 1em;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.tooltip-inner:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 1px;
  width: 40px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-DhY6onE6f3zzKbjUPRc2hOzGAdEf4/Dz+WJwBvEYL/lkkIsI3ihufq9hk9K4lVoK" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-BOsAfwzjNJHrJ8cZidOg56tcQWfp6y72vEJ8xQ9w6Quywb24iOsW913URv1IS4GD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button>
```